# PHP html_entity_decode() exception for numeric HTML entities 60 and 62

Tags: php

How do I use PHP's `html_entity_decode()` with an exception for numeric HTML entities 60 and 62?

Currently my code looks something like the following:

```
$t = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,html_entity_decode($_POST['title'],ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8'));
```

However if I have  that are encoded to display as carets in content (just as you would display an ampersand directly to a client) they too become encoded and this has led to malformed HTML. So I need to make some sort of exception though I'm not sure how to do this; string replacement with a temporary placeholder? I'm sure there is a better way.

Comment: What is the *purpose* of 'decoding' the posted value? It seems like .. something is wrong with doing such. Normally an HTML input field will *not* 'encode' any values.

Comment: I support many different non-Latin languages and client browsers, PHP and everything else in the mix jump at every oppertunity to destroy HTML entities so when pages are edited I convert **all** characters over 127 in to numeric HTML entities which keeps them safe...when putting them in to  the database the length becomes an issue however SQL properly supports Unicode/UTF-8 so this is the last step to ensure the client sees what the client needs to. :-)

Comment: I don't see how [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) is designed to handle such (or can handle it correctly).

Comment: @user2864740 When you have an entity like `&#60;` and `&#62;` (the < and > caret characters) if you convert them to regular characters then there is zero distinction in the system how to convert them back so they **must** remain encoded when going in to the database; never allow code to be stored subjective to requiring human interpretation because websites aren't manually served by humans, they're automatically served by servers and software.

Comment: So how does 'decoding' something relate to "must remain encoded"? The browser sends back text that is *not encoded*. The core problem is trying to decode something that has *no right being decoded*. Don't start with 'decode' - then explore a solution / ask a question starting back there, before the current issue was introduced, and there will likely be a better approach.

Comment: @user2864740 Say you're using a system to teach people to code HTML in a non-Latin language (Arabic, Armenian, Hebrew, Russian, etc); you must use `<` and `>` in HTML yet when you want those carets to be displayed as text they *must* remain encoded. The problem I'm facing is to ensure that encoded carets remain encoded but that absolutely everything else be decoded. I am almost certain that I will be creating a custom function that does string replacement, decodes and then does a second string replacement to achieve this; I'm stronger on client than server so I was hoping I missed something.

Comment: Is the goal simply to "allow people to enter in text using an HTML-like-encoding method for entities"? (Why they would want to do this, instead of using the their characterset, I don't know .. but at least it would a sufficient enough 'reason' to narrow down the problem which *still starts from incorrectly applying across-the-board HTML decoding*.

Comment: Also, `<` and `>` are better called *angle brackets*. `^` is a *caret* (and is unaffected by HTML encoding or decoding).

Comment: @user2864740 I responded to VolkerK's answer this approach has produced the most reliable results in a fairly punishing series of tests. Thank you for the clarification in regards to angle bracket not being carets, I try to use proper references all the time. People enter in their content as they normally would in either the visual or HTML editing modes; when the editor is submitted *then* all characters above 127 are converted and I think when switching back to the HTML editing mode. You're welcomed to visit my profile link and see the old version's corrupted language sets on the front page.

Answer (score 1):

Tentative answer, since this might be an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem):
After resolving the html entities you can "re-encode" those characters that could hurt your html structure via [htmlspecialchars](http://docs.php.net/htmlspecialchars).

```
$t = mysqli_real_escape_string(
    $db,
    htmlspecialchars(
        html_entity_decode($_POST['title'],ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8'),
        'UTF-8'
    )
);
```

Comment: I think the problem there is that PHP will have zero clue or possibility to understand which carets are to be encoded and which should be entities. So unless there is a built in exception or different function I can use I should probably create my own function that temporarily does string replacement before and after using `html_entity_decode()`.

Comment: Or you apply the encoding not when storing the values but on output. If that has a negative effect on the performance -> caching ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately that would be a double-negative for me. While encoded as numeric entities the very intentional limitations of the SQL fields such as for meta descriptions don't compensate for numeric HTML entities and I really can't afford the slightest shred of time to adjust that plus it makes little sense. Additionally every time the editor switches to HTML mode (from visual) JavaScript converts all the characters over code 127 to entities any way. I'm not seeing an alternative to the double string replacement that I was hoping for; I just want to do what my clients want though. :-)

Comment: no no, I only meant the encoding, not the decoding: html_entity_decode() without caring about < and/or >, i.e. storing < and > as-is, but on the outside apply htmlspecialchars().

Comment: I tried that and it deletes the string content from the variable. :-\

Comment: Oh, JavaScript does not encode carets on my system because they are numbered 60 and 62 and it only encodes above 127; damn I can't stand that the enter to create comments triggers when using spellcheck. -__-